# geom_dotplot dot sizes change when plotting different datasets in loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to do many dot plots for different subsets of a dataset. Problem is that the format is not the same across plots. In particular, the size of the dots is not the same.

The range of the "y" variable is not the same across subsets. Is this the reason?

```
rm(list=ls()) 
library(ggplot2)

outdir<-"SELECT YOUR OUTPUT DIRECTORY"

#generate subsets separately
set.seed(1)
#
data1<-rbind(
  data.frame(poll=rnorm(20,20,5),zone="zone1"),
  data.frame(poll=rnorm(20,16,1),zone="zone2"))
data1$id="ID1"

data2<-rbind(
  data.frame(poll=rnorm(20,2,3),zone="zone1"),
  data.frame(poll=rnorm(20,2,1),zone="zone2"))
data2$id="ID2"

#this is the sample full data set
alldata<-rbind(data1,data2)

ids<-unique(alldata$id)

for (i in ids) {
  graphdata<-subset(alldata, id==i)

  p<-ggplot(graphdata, aes(x=zone, y=poll)) + 
    geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', binwidth=0.8, 
                 method="histodot",stackratio=0.8, dotsize=0.5) +
    ggtitle(i)

  fname<-paste(outdir,"/",i,".png",sep="")
  ggsave(fname,last_plot())
}
```

Comment: welcome to SO. please read how to create an MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. we need sample data and correct assigned objects, i.e. working code to help you. Test the code of your question in a clean R session and you will see, it doesn't work.

Comment: can you provide a small sample of dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `geom_dotplot` looks like a dot plot, it's actually a different representation of a histogram. If we look at `?geom_dotplot`, we see that the the size of the dots is not an absolute size, but is based on the width of the bins relative to the x-axis or y-axis (as appropriate):

> In a dot plot, the width of a dot corresponds to the bin width ...

And the `dotsize` argument (contrary to what you might expect) just scales the size of the dots by a relative factor:

> dotsize: The diameter of the dots relative to binwidth, default 1.

We can see this with an example:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) +
  geom_dotplot(binwidth = 1.5, stackdir = "center")
```

[image]

By scaling the x-axis by three while keeping `binwidth` constant, we reduce the relative size of these bins relative to the axis and the dots shrink:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg*3)) +
  geom_dotplot(binwidth = 1.5, stackdir = "center")
```

[image]

If we multiply the size of the `binwidth` by three, the relative size of the bins is the same and the dots are the same size as the first example:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg*3)) +
  geom_dotplot(binwidth = 4.5, stackdir = "center")
```

[image]

We can also compensate by setting `dotsize = 3` (up from its default value of 1). This makes the dots 3x larger so they match the size of the dots in the first example, despite the bins being smaller relative to the axis. Note that they overlap now, since the dots are larger than the space the take up on the x-axis:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg*3)) +
  geom_dotplot(binwidth = 1.5, stackdir = "center", dotsize = 3)
```

[image]

If you want your dots to be the same size, I'd use a dynamic value for `dotsize` to scale them. There's probably a more elegant way to do this, but as a simple attempt, I'd calculate the maximum range of the y-axis for all your datasets:

```
# Put this outside the loop
#   and choose whatever dataset has the largest range
max_y_range <- max(data1$poll) - min(data1$poll)
```

then in your loop, set:

```
dotsize = (max(graphdata$poll) - min(graphdata$poll))/max_y_range
```

This should scale your dots properly as the y-axis changes between plots:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Beyond @divibisan's excellent explaination, you might also want to look at the [ggpubr](http://www.sthda.com/english/rpkgs/ggpubr/) package which I recently came across. You can simply use `ggdotplot` and get nicer graphs.

Here is you original graph. I changed the plotting code a little.

```
set.seed(1)
#
data1<-rbind(
  data.frame(poll=rnorm(20,20,5),zone="zone1"),
  data.frame(poll=rnorm(20,16,1),zone="zone2"))
data1$id="ID1"

data2<-rbind(
  data.frame(poll=rnorm(20,2,3),zone="zone1"),
  data.frame(poll=rnorm(20,2,1),zone="zone2"))
data2$id="ID2"

#this is the sample full data set
alldata<-rbind(data1,data2)

alldata %>% ggplot(aes(x=zone, y=poll)) + 
  geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', binwidth=0.8, 
               method="histodot",stackratio=0.8, dotsize=0.5) +
  facet_wrap(~id, scale="free_y")
```

[image: figure1]

Here is how you can draw using [ggdotplot](http://www.sthda.com/english/rpkgs/ggpubr/reference/ggdotplot.html).

```
library(ggpubr)

alldata %>% ggdotplot(x="zone", y="poll", fill="zone", size=1.5)+
  facet_wrap(~id, scale="free_y")
```

[image: figure2]

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work around for using dotplot without manually feeding dotsize. Not very elegant but it does the trick,

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) +
       geom_dotplot(binwidth = 1, stackdir = "center")

maxY <- max(ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]$x)
my_binwidth = maxY/30

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) +
       geom_dotplot(binwidth = my_binwidth, stackdir = "center", dotsize = 1) 
p
##############################################################################
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg * 3)) +
       geom_dotplot(binwidth = 1, stackdir = "center")
     
maxY <- max(ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]$x)
my_binwidth = maxY/30

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg * 3)) +
       geom_dotplot(binwidth = my_binwidth, stackdir = "center", dotsize = 1) 
p
```

So you will have to build a fake plot with geom_dotplot to get the max value by `ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]$y`, which you can use to specify binwidth in your actual plot. The dot size will remain constant irrespective of the maximum data size. If the dot size is larger or smaller to your taste then you can multiply `my_binwidth` by an appropriate factor. Note that it's important to keep dotsize as constant. Increasing binwidth will proportionally change the dotsize.