# Varying dotsizes in ggplot2's geom_dotplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a dotplot where a numerical y values are grouped according to character variables. That works fine, but I also want to change the sizes of the dots according to another variable, so that there are three differrent sizes of dots in the plot. I can change the dot sizes, it's just that R doesn't seem to be getting it right.

I couldn't find a good sample dataset, so I've made a quick example:

```
#Making some sufficient data:
y1 <- c(1,1,2,3,4,5,6,6)
x1 <- c('A','A','B','C','A','A','B','B') 
size1 <- c(0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.6,0.6,1.0)

data1 <- data.frame(x1,y1,size1)
data1

#define size as a vector: apparently it helps some problems
size2 <- data1$size1 

#plot my dotplot! 
ggplot(data1, aes(x=x1,y=y1)) + 
geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", stackdir="center", dotsize=size2)
```

Overall, the dotplot works fine. The y variables are grouped according to their group of A, B, or C. However, the dotsizes are incorrect: The only dot in group C should be small (dotsize=0.3), the two dots at y=1 of group A should both be of equal size... and so on.

[Dotplot with all sorts of dotsize inaccuracies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpvEq.png)

The question 'geom_dotplot dot sizes change when plotting different datasets in loop' ([geom_dotplot dot sizes change when plotting different datasets in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52212304/geom-dotplot-dot-sizes-change-when-plotting-different-datasets-in-loop))  said that the dotsize of geom_dotplot wasn't exactly a dot size, but was relative to bin width. That could explain why I'm having trouble. However, I'm unsure of how to fix this. Is there a way to reliably vary dot sizes in ggplot2's dotplots, or should I try making a dotplot with a more flexible tool than geom_dotplot? (Restarting R and my computer don't work.)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Using `geom_point` instead of `geom_dotplot` should solve the problem

```
ggplot(data1, aes(x=x1,y=y1)) + 
     geom_point(aes(size=size1))
```

[image: resultingplot]

Comment: `binaxis`, `stackdir` are not `geom_point` params by the way. You don't need them.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the dotplot stacking function while using geom_point? I have multiple points at the same y value, and they aren't all displayed using geom_point. I really need each data point to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

The stack overflow thread you shared clarifies what you can do with `geom_dotplot` and if you add a `binwidth` param, you can see the effect of `dotsize`. Here is an example,

```r
base <- ggplot(data1, aes(x=x1,y=y1))
base + geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", stackdir="center", dotsize=size1, binwidth = 1)
```

## Output

[image: dot_plot]